# List files not changed for more than 1 month

Tags: git

I'm trying to find files that were not changed in the last X months, so I can maybe delete them or move them to other repo (if it makes sense).

I know I can list the files changed in the last 10 days, for example, doing something like this:

```
$ git log --pretty="format:" --since="2 days ago" --name-only | sort | uniq
```

So far, the best idea I have to do what I want would be to list all files ever added, and then all files changed in the last X months, and finally diff the 2 lists:

```
$ git log --pretty="format:" --since="1 year ago" --name-only | sort | uniq > 1_year
$ git log --pretty="format:" --name-only | sort | uniq > all
$ diff 1_year all
```

Problem is: this probably ain't right, since some files were deleted, others moved/renamed/etcl...

Is there any way I can get such list from git command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print just the files that are unchanged use:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'
```

You can than sort them by date etc. Hope it helps.